# Terminal Operation Times Out (Recent Python Install Issues)

Tags: python, terminal, homebrew, out, timed

I was stupid and may have deleted some dependencies for mac's base python (and/or python 2.7) as root when trying to uninstall anaconda navigator.

Now every  Every time I try to perform an install or update action in terminal - the operation times out.

For example: 'brew update' in terminal has the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew failed!
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
```

(NOTE: I checked, and /usr/local/Homebrew/homebrew-core exists.)

Another example: 'pip3 install PyQt5' returns the following:

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1086a8320>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyqt5/
```

I also tried to install python 3.7 in terminal, and the operation times out. I was able to install python 3.7 via pkg download, but the terminal problem persists.

I have the following questions (1) how can I find out if the terminal timeout issue was caused by my deleting some essential mac python dependency, (2) whether the answer is yes or no, how do I go about fixing this issue?

Just so you're aware...

```
which python
```

returns the following...

```
/usr/bin/python
```

This is my complete .bash_profile...

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Try to reinstall homebrew with `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`.

Comment: I tried to reinstall homebrew using your command, but received another time-out error: `curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 `. I'm actually now hearing buzz around the office about added security measures for my company. For example, I now can't install anything on my work computer whatsoever. I'm guessing that's the cause of my issue. Very frustrating, but at least I know the problem isn't related to any action on my part!